# How to include exception when using fill everything?

Tags: r, merge, fill

I'm merging two data frames as follows:

```
data_merged <- full_join(df1, df2, by=c("col1","col2")) %>%
  fill(everything(), .direction = 'down')
```

However, there is a column in the new merged data frame that I don't want to fill (say, `col3`). This row needs to retain its NA value. I've tried doing this with `select` but failed, and also thought of maybe working around with making part of it a tibble but can't capitalize on the idea.

Does anybody have any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
data.frame(col1 = 1:10, col2 = c(1, NA), col3 = c(2,NA))%>%
fill(!col3, .direction = 'down')

#     col1 col2 col3
# 1     1    1    2
# 2     2    1   NA
# 3     3    1    2
# 4     4    1   NA
# 5     5    1    2
# 6     6    1   NA
# 7     7    1    2
# 8     8    1   NA
# 9     9    1    2
# 10   10    1   NA
```

Comment: This isn't working once implemented in my code and I'm not getting any errors. The fill still fills in the column and I don't know why

Comment: You should post some real data and code of your own, so that people can understand the problem!

Answer (score 0):

We can also use `na.locf` from `zoo`

```
library(zoo)
df1$col3 <- na.locf0(df1$col3)
```

#### data

```
df1 <- data.frame(col1 = 1:10, col2 = c(1, NA), col3 = c(2,NA))
```